# match arraylist index and Value of array in android

Tags: android, arrays

I want to match index values of `ArrayList` elements with values from an int array.  `Pos` array contains selected items, while the `ArrayList` object contains all items.

I want a new `ArrayList` containing selected items only, but the `if` condition turns out to be always `false`

```
        for (int i = 0; i < Pos.length; i++) {
            Category state = stateList.get(i);

            if(stateList.indexOf(i)==Pos[i]) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"match",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Drawer.add(state);
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Drawer.size(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: So what issue you are facing?

Comment: its can't give output , Don't match index value and Array Value

Comment: Try to print the position values.

Comment: @AanalShah What are you trying to do?

Comment: statelist.indexof(i) give -1 value and, position give proper values

Comment: i m trying to match index of Arraylist and Array values .statelist is Arraylist and Pos is int Array

Comment: @AanalShah Does `Pos` array have selected indices from the `stateList` array?

Comment: yes it content seleted item from statelist

Comment: @AanalShah And you are trying to add the select items to `Drawer` Array. Isn't it?

Comment: yes Drawer is Array list

Comment: @AanalShah Check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have selected indices from `stateList` in the `Pos` array. So just get the items in `stateList` using the `Pos` array. Try this code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Pos.length; i++) {
    Drawer.add(stateList.get(Pos[i]));
}
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Drawer.size(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

PLease try this -

```
     if (i == Pos[i]) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Drawer.add(state);
}
```

Comment: yeah Pleasure.    :)